# Save Javascript Array For Use in Another File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

Editing to try and add clarity:

I have two files: number-crunching.js and chart.html.

`number-crunching.js` has a JSON object:

```
var data = [
{
  "mother": "Ellen",
  "father": "Bob",
  "pet": "cat",
  "age":50,
  "hairLength":10
},

{
  "mother": "Sandra",
  "father": "Jeff",
  "pet": "dog",
  "age":18,
  "hairLength":2
}
];
```

Then it has a `run` function that processes that data and returns a multi-dimensional array like this:

```
[
  ['mother', 'father', 'pet', 'age', 'hairLength'],
  ['Ellen', 'Bob', 'cat', 50, 10],
  ['Sandra, 'Jeff', 'dog', 18, 2]
]
```

Everything that goes into creating this array is wrapped in a function called `run` that returns the finished array.

In the second file chart.html (which has some JS) I include number-crunching.js and call the run function and store that array in chart.html.

var editedData = run();
   editedData now contains the array above.

I then visualize the contents of editedData in a chart on an html page.

The chart takes forever to load because it is doing all the calculations in the run function every single time, which involve looping through the JSON object many times and it is a really big object. So it takes forever to load on the page.

What I want to do is separate these files. So, instead of calling `run` in `chart.html`, I want to just store the array in chart.html. So, I want to run number-crunching once and save the array somehow so I don't have to do any more number-crunching.

Essentially, I only want to use number-crunching and its`run` **once**. That is, it should save the results of `run` somewhere so that I can copy the array into the chart.html file and use that for my web application.

How can I do this? Thanks for your help and sorry if it wasn't clear the first time.

Comment: If this question is about code you've written, where is the code?

Comment: `JSON.parse(/*jsons here*/)` <- this makes the brackets go away

Comment: Did you already try [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Comment: Hopefully the edited description is easier to understand. Thank you very much for your responses.

Comment: I still don't think I understand.  Is the data in the array static or does it change?  If it's not dynamic, why not just save the array to a .js file and include it?  And what do you mean by "it is doing all the calculations in the run function every single time".  Every time the page is loaded?

Comment: That's what I want to do! Yes, the array doesn't change. I want to save it in a file and include it (or alternatively include it in the chart file). My question is how do I save the array.

Comment: "it is doing all the calculations in the run function every single time" -> Yes, every time the page is loaded. I just want to execute run once and save the array to my own computer or include it in chart html so I don't have to use run or the other file anymore and can just use the array in my web application.

Comment: If all you need is the array, just do: var myArray = [ ['mother', 'father', 'pet', 'age', 'hairLength'], ['Ellen', 'Bob', 'cat', 50, 10], ['Sandra, 'Jeff', 'dog', 18, 2] ];

Comment: My goal is to not execute the run function again ever. I want to store the array without the run function. When I upload the code to the server and it is on my website, I want there to be no run function. The array will be there, but it will be in the chart file, stored, without the run function. The run function and the number-crunching file were just used to create the array and now that I have the array, I don't need that file anymore. Ever.

Comment: So I will copy var myArray = [ ['mother', 'father', 'pet', 'age', 'hairLength'], ['Ellen', 'Bob', 'cat', 50, 10], ['Sandra, 'Jeff', 'dog', 18, 2] ]; into the chart file where I will visualize it. But I don't know how to get the array without the run function. I don't know how I can just copy the result of the run function so I can paste it into the chart file and store it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the [HTML5's FileSystem](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

You need to create a file and push your array into it in JSON format.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4dup9/)

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

function errorHandler(err) {
   console.log("Error happened");
   console.log(err);
}

var yourdata = [
  ['mother', 'father', 'pet', 'age', 'hairLength'],
  ['Ellen', 'Bob', 'cat', 50, 10],
  ['Sandra', 'Jeff', 'dog', 18, 2]
];

function onInitFs(fs) {

    fs.root.getFile('data.json', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
            fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
console.log('Write completed.');
            };

            fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
console.log('Write failed: ' + e);
            };

            var json = JSON.stringify(yourdata);
            console.log(json);
            var blob = new Blob([json], {type: "application/json"});
            fileWriter.write(blob);
        }, errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler);

}

window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(PERSISTENT, 1024, function(grantedBytes) {
    // Is this a bug? This function is called instantly, i didn't even granted permission or anything. You need to refresh after granting permission.
    window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onInitFs, errorHandler);
}, errorHandler);
```

Comment: This seems like it is on the right path. I am getting an error when I put this in that says Uncaught TypeWrror: undefined is not a function. and it is showing on the last line. Could you please help me figure out what the problem is here so that I may get the file? It won't let me edit the post because it is only one character changed, but I changed the declaration of the function to be errorHandler to match the function calls.

Comment: This is what I have now: function errorHandler() {
        console.log("Error happened");
    }

    function onInitFs(fs) {

      var yourdata = run();

      fs.root.getFile('datascotus.json', {create: true},     function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
          var json = JSON.stringify(yourdata);
          var blob = new Blob([json], {type: "application/json"});
          fileWriter.write(blob);
        }, errorHandler);
      }, errorHandler);

    }

    window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, onInitFs,     errorHandler);

Comment: @Roger Edited my answer, never worked with filesystem api, so sorry for waiting, i made a sample code for you (it works, tested). You can find the fiddle in the answer or here: http://jsfiddle.net/4dup9/